# Bharanyasam versus samashrayanam - dos and donts

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

My namaskaram to all the knowledgeable folks here. Pardon adiyen's (my) ignorance here and please shed light on what are the differences between the two -
*all i know is that samashrayanam is what thenkali sect of sri vaishnavites do and end there, while vadakalai sect do Bharanyasam in addition to samashrayanam and both of these mean saranagathi.*

Also please shed some light on the dos and donts once having received either or both, specifically related to

i)  Prapatti

ii) Food Habits (satvic food only/is it mandatory)

iii) Are thenkalais allowed to take bharanyasam as well? if no, may i know why?

iv) Daily mandatory rituals if any others that i might not even be knowledgeable enough to ask

Thank you all!